# How to Implicitly Call a Function Call Operator?

Tags: c++, templates, function-call-operator

How does one *implicitly call* a class object's templated *function call* operator?

```
class User_Type
{
public:
    template< typename T > T operator()() const;
};

void function()
{
    User_Type user_var;
    int int_var_0 = user_var.operator()< int >(); // explicit function call operator; ugly.
    int int_var_1 = user_var< int >(); // implicit function call operator.
}
```

`g++-4.9 -Wall -Wextra`'s output error is:

```
    error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
        auto int_var_1 = user_var< int >();
                                   ^
```

Comment: What is the point of this if you have 'implicit conversions' (as you mentioned in a comment) ?

Comment: @DieterLücking I want a symbol to act as a "conceptual value", and know how to represent itself as many different types.

Comment: @DieterLücking Think of the statement `T val = 0`; this is valid for any fundamental type.  I want to provide a `T val = foo` that is valid for any fundamental type, and user-extended types.  In my case `foo` is a namespace static instance of class `Foo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the template argument needs to be specified explicitly, then you can't. The only way to specify it is to use your first syntax.

If the template argument can be deduced from the function arguments, or has a default, then you can use simple function-call syntax if you want that argument.

Depending on what the type is used for, it might make sense to make the class, rather than the member, a template, so you can specify the argument when declaring the object.

Comment: That's a real bummer.  *sigh*  Do you happen to have a keyword or a full chapter & paragraph reference into the Standard doc which might explain this?

Comment: My class itself cannot take one template parameter; it acts as an object that can be converted to `T`, by definition.

Comment: My class already has `template< typename T > operator T () const` defined, which works when implicit conversions work.  I wanted another method to provide an explicit syntax.  :-/

Comment: @CharlesLWilcox why not use a template explicit conversion operator ? Edit : what's wrong with calling the conversion operator explicitly ?

Comment: @CharlesLWilcox: I'd use a function template called `as` or something for that. `user_var.as<int>()` is perhaps a nicer idiom than `user_var<int>()` in any case.

Comment: @Quentin, I've defined the *conversion operator*.  However, `static_cast< T >( user_var )` can be ambiguous, depending upon `T`'s defined *conversion constructors*.

Comment: @CharlesLWilcox indeed.

Comment: I still wish I knew why there was this syntactic limitation, but I guess I have to accept it.  `std::reference_wrapper`, and `boost::optional` both use an explicit `get` operator, instead of a function-call operator.

Answer (score 0):

There is just no way. it's possible to cheat a bit with a non-used parameter like

```
class User_Type
{
public:
    template< typename T > T operator()( T * ) const;
};

void function()
{
    User_Type user_var;
    int int_var_1 = user_var((int*)0); // implicit function call operator.
}
```

but it will not be what you precisely want.

Comment: Yea.. I considered that, after I considered a "fill by reference", but it still makes usage less streamlined.